# Polymer Paper-Dialog not visible

Tags: dialog, polymer

On my page I want to disaply a Polymer Paper-Dialog so I wrote an own element that looks like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-dialog" constructor="MyDialog" extends="paper-dialog" noscript>
    <template>
        <span>I'm a dialog!</span>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Now I tried to display the dialog with this JS code:

```
var dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.toggle();
```

But the dialog does not show up. Any ideas why?

Comment: Any JS errors? Are you wrapping that code in the `polymer-ready` event?

Comment: No there are no JS errors. I call the code inside a click Event from another web component. Do I have to attache the new object at first to the document or something like this? If I only call an `allert(...)` in the click method it works great.

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's because you're creating a new dialog, but not putting it in the DOM anywhere.  Try putting the markup in your html, and then getting a reference to it in JS and calling toggle.  Or take a look at the Core-overlay element and see if that does what you want.

Comment: So I have to call `document.attache(...)`  or something else? Is this not done by the `toggle` method? Or what do you excatly mean?

Comment: Toggle just shows/hides a dialog that is already on the page.  It doesn't put the dialog into the DOM.

Comment: Okay thank you for that. Can your write this in an answer so I can mark this here as done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating a new Dialog in your javascript function, you aren't adding it to the DOM anywhere.  So, when you call toggle on it, it tries to show/hide a dialog that hasn't been added to the page.

If you want this to work, you should be adding the markup for the dialog to your html, getting a reference to that element in javascript, and then calling toggle.

Something else you could consider doing is looking at the Core-Overlay polymer element.  It handles a lot of the dialog functions for you, and even allows you to shade everything that isn't in the dialog itself.